# How can I use this kind of index?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to use a type of index and doesn't work. Maybe you can help me to realize what I'm doing wrong.

This is the definition of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TIR"."INT07NCMP"(
    "INT07_CORRELATIVO" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "INT07_CENTRO" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_CODCOMPONENTE" VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_ALMCOMPONENTE" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_CANCOMPONENTE" NUMBER(13,3), 
    "INT07_UNICOMPONENTE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "INT07_CODPORTADOR" VARCHAR2(18 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_ALMPORTADOR" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_CANPORTADOR" NUMBER(13,3), 
    "INT07_UNIPORTADOR" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "INT07_ALMDESTINO" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_FECINICIO" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_HORINICIO" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "INT07_FECTERMINO" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT07_HORTERMINO" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "INT07_ESTPOCH" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "INT07_TMPPOCH" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "INT07_ESTSAP" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "INT07_TMPSAP" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "INT07_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "INT07NCMP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("INT07_CORRELATIVO"),
    CONSTRAINT "INT07NCMP_UK1" UNIQUE (
        "INT07_CENTRO", "INT07_CODCOMPONENTE", "INT07_ALMCOMPONENTE", "INT07_CODPORTADOR", "INT07_ALMPORTADOR",
        "INT07_FECINICIO", "INT07_HORINICIO", "INT07_FECTERMINO", "INT07_HORTERMINO"
    )
);
```

and this are the indexes that I created:

```
CREATE INDEX "TIR"."INT07NCMP_IDX1" ON "TIR"."INT07NCMP" ("INT07_CENTRO", "INT07_ESTPOCH");
CREATE INDEX "TIR"."INT07NCMP_IDX2" ON "TIR"."INT07NCMP" ("INT07_CENTRO", "INT07_ESTSAP");
CREATE INDEX "TIR"."INT07NCMP_IDX3" ON "TIR"."INT07NCMP" ("INT07_CENTRO", "INT07_CORRELATIVO", "INT07_FECINICIO", "INT07_HORINICIO", "INT07_FECTERMINO", "INT07_HORTERMINO");
```

Using "Explain plan" I'm good with indexes 1 and 2 but no with index 3. For example I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM INT07NCMP
WHERE INT07_CENTRO = '7100'
AND INT07_CORRELATIVO > 0
```

and this is the answer:

```
Plan hash value: 2810525850

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                |  9770 |  1450K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| INT07NCMP      |  9770 |  1450K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | INT07NCMP_IDX1 |    39 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("INT07_CORRELATIVO">0)
   2 - access("INT07_CENTRO"='7100')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

So, as you can see, only IDX1 was used and I expected to use IDX3 because I'm filtering with "INT07_CENTRO" and then "INT07_CORRELATIVO", just like the order of index definition. If i try putting more filters (all the columns of IDX3) It doesn't work either.

Any hint for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you gathered statistics on this table? E.g. `BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('TIR', 'INT07NCMP'); END;`, then re-check the query plan.

Comment: What proportion of rows have INT07_CORRELATIVO > 0? If it's most of them then the index isn't very selective and the optimiser might as well pick a smaller one, or no index, as INT07NCMP_IDX3 is no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have good stats.  num_rows in user_tables and user_indexes.

Give that, best approach in these cases is to simply trust that db is making the right decision.  it considers a lot of aspects, e.g. stats physical orgzniation etc.  So make indexes as they should bae and create query per the rules of data and then trust the db.

In very few cases, you may have to force the query.  You can use hints.  But in this case unless it makes a huge differnece which I doubt - just adding the correlatoivo at the end of first index will be fine.  Because saving will come not from a range scan on this but that oracle did not have to go to database table to get that and index scan was enough

Comment: And in this case it's safe to assume that the table does *not* have good stats, because `- dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)` implies statistics were not gathered on the table at all.  OP should check that the auto-stats job is running every night.